# Set activity audio stream to android home audio stream

Tags: java, android

I want to set my activity and the soundpool to the audio stream that I can adjust when I am on the home screen (I presume this is the main stream?).

What stream is this? What is its name?

**Update:**

Currently I am using the `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`, however when I set the audio level of my phone to 0 and then open my app, the audio is level is back to 100, which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean which volume it is that gets adjusted when you press the volume keys while at the home screen, then it's most likely the ring volume (i.e. [STREAM_RING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_RING)).

Comment: this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_RING); has no effect. Do I perhaps need to set a permission?

Comment: `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)` only says that while your activity has focus, pressing the volume keys should adjust the volume for `STREAM_RING`. That didn't seem like what you were trying to achieve based on your question.